# Most pythonic way to reorder repeating list

Tags: python, list

What is the most pythonic way to reorder a list of the format:

```
l = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 
     'C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 
     'G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 
     'T1', 'T2', 'T3', 'T4']
```

To:

```
l = ['A1', 'C1', 'G1', 'T1', 
     'A2', 'C2', 'G2', 'T2', 
     'A3', 'C3', 'G3', 'T3', 
     'A4', 'C4', 'G4', 'T4']
```

The simplest solution I've come up with is `l = l[::4] + l[1::4] + l[2::4] + l[3::4]`, but it doesn't seem the cleanest way.

Comment: Is this about sorting a list, or is it about a matrix transpose on a list that, when split exactly the right way, happens to look like a square matrix?

Comment: It is about a list that happens to look like a square matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's sort is stable. So you can sort it based on the second character, like this

```
print sorted(l, key=lambda item: item[1])
```

Or an inplace sort,

```
l.sort(key=lambda item: item[1])
```

As pointed out by "undefined is not a function" in the comments, if the number part has more than 1 digits, then you can do

```
print sorted(l, key=lambda item: int(item[1:]))
```

Comment: or `int(item[1:])` if the integers can be of more than just one character.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the list by the second character in each string. Python sorting is stable, so elements with the same second character will stay in the same order. The code for this is just:

```
l = sorted(l, key=lambda e: e[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will produce the second list, regardless of the initial ordering.

```
sorted(l, key=lambda item:item[::-1])
```